# Using a rake task that accepts parameters as a prerequisite

Tags: ruby, rake

According to http://rake.rubyforge.org/files/doc/rakefile_rdoc.html, you can create a task that accepts parameters and also has prerequisites:

```
task :name, [:first_name, :last_name] => [:pre_name] do |t, args|
```

But what if :pre_name is a task that also accepts parameters? What is the syntax for passing parameters to :pre_name when it is used as a prerequisite?

Answer (score 9):

It's actually pretty simple - the :pre task will receive the same parameters as the original task. All you need to do is make sure that the signature is similar - for instance if the first task receives :a,:b the :pre task needs to receive them as well.

See more here: [rake with params](http://arubyguy.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/running-rake-with-parameters/)

Comment: Excellent! Just what i needed!

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm late to the party, but I had the same problem and figured something out that didn't use environment variables. You can use `Rake::Task.invoke` to do this. Here's an example for a database backup rake task:

```
namespace :db do
    task :dump_db, [:dump_file, :rails_env] do |t, args|
        puts "dumping to #{args[:dump_file]} with rails env = #{args[:rails_env]}"
    end

    task :stop_slave do
        puts "stopping slave"
    end

    task :start_slave do
        puts "starting slave"
    end

    task :upload_dump, [:dump_file] do |t, args|
        puts "uploading #{args[:dump_file]}"
    end

    task :backup_to_s3, [:dump_file, :rails_env] do |t, args|
        Rake::Task["db:stop_slave"].invoke()
        Rake::Task["db:dump_db"].invoke(args[:dump_file], args[:rails_env])
        Rake::Task["db:start_slave"].invoke()
        Rake::Task["db:upload_dump"].invoke(args[:dump_file])
    end
end
```

Comment: While this works, note that it won't set up the invoked task as an explicit prerequisite dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct answer, but I do have an alternative solution that might work for you.  None of my rake tasks use parameters.  (I think I tried to use parameters and had trouble getting them to work.)  Instead, I rely on the ENV array.  So, for example, I would write that example task as:

```
task :name =>:pre_name do
  do_something_with_name(ENV['first_name'], ENV['last_name'])
end
```

which would be invoked as:

```
$ rake name first_name=John last_name=Smith
```

The ENV array data would be available to the pre_name task as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
namespace :shell do

  desc "Local hostname"
  task :hostname do
    puts "Local hostname"
    sh "hostname"
  end

  desc "Local uptime"
  task :uptime do
    puts "Local uptime"
    sh "uptime"
  end

  desc "Echo something"
  task :echo,[:someword] do |t,args|
    puts "--- #{args[:someword]} ---"
  end

end 


desc "Run all tasks"
task :all , [:someword] => ["shell:hostname","shell:uptime","shell:echo"] do
  puts "Done."
end
```

Comment: You can mark source code with 4 leading spaces - but what do you want to answer? Please give some informations what you want to say with your coding example..